# Is any way to read text and execute that such a code command in C++?

Tags: c++, qt

I want to capture color rgb data from a text box with (r,g,b,a) format And create:

```
QColor mColor = QColor(r,g,b,a);
```

Is any way to read text  and execute that such a code command?
For example If we assume that `execute` does this :D:

```
mColor = execute ("QColor"+"(r,g,b,a)");
```

Is it possible?

Comment: No, not unless you want to implement your own C++-based scripting language.

Comment: Since you have tagged your question `Qt`, perhaps you would be interested in [QML](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.10/qmlapplications.html) as an alternative?

Comment: Is there a reason you want to eval a string instead of just reading the four variables `r,g,b,a` from your text box?

Comment: I developed a signal plotter. In its setting I want to add  number of curve and for each curve I define it's pattern, color ,...
for this I use a table. if eval of string was possible, it's easy for me to input parameter in Qt format.

Comment: If you define your table columns as `red`, `green`, `blue`, then it would be easy to do as @Useless suggested and convert those to integral values which can be passed to the `QColor` constructor.

Comment: There is many way to do this. Thanks for your suggestion. I was looking for the easy way and @ Some programmer dude said nope! there isn't such way!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are many ways, I'll list a few:
**The `if` statement:**

```
std::string command;
if (command == "QColor")
{
   m_color = //...;
}
```

**Using `std::map`**

```
typedef (void) (*Function_Pointer)(const std::string& arguments);
void ProcessQColorCommand(const std::string& arguments);
std::map<string, Function_Pointer> dispatcher;
dispatcher["QColor"] = ProcessQColorCommand;
//...
std::map<string, Function_Pointer>::iterator iter;
iter = dispatcher.find(command);
if (iter != dispatcher.end())
{
  (*iter->second)(arguments);
}
```

You could also make a table of string and function pointer and use that.

You may want to research "lexing" and "parsing" too.

Answer (score 0):

Let me rephrase just to make sure I understand correctly what you asked:

You get a QString, that can be user input, and looks like:

"mColor = execute (\"QColor\"+\"(r,g,b,a)\");"

And you want to build a QColor object by analysing this QString and detect the correct parameters? So essentially you need a function that takes QString as Input and gives a QColor as output ?

In that case, I think you should use regular expressions (http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qregularexpression.html). That should help you to extract the required information from the QString, knowing what its structure is supposed to be (and also to detect if the syntax is incorrect).

It all depends on the complexity of what you are trying to detect. For something very simple, you can just use a good-old "if" statement, as Thomas Matthews suggested.

For something a bit more complex, Regular Expressions are a good option.

And then if you need to be able to interpret more complicated inputs, you'll have to do a full parser. But in your case, I doubt that you 'd need to go that far.

Comment: Thank you for your time. I looking for global solution if possible, not just for Qcolor. If you familiar with MATLAB , this software has a eval() function that execute MATLAB expression in text .  I looking for same  function as eval as in c++.